# Integrating $\int_0^ {2} \frac {1}{{(x^2+2x+10)}^2}^~dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^ {2} \frac {1}{{(x^2+2x+10)}^2}^~dx$$

someone can help me solve this integral. I can not solve it

Comment: A similar question was just asked.

Answer (score 1):

*HINTs*  :

1)$x+1 = u$, so $du = dx$

2)$u = 3\tan(t)$.

Comment: i get: t/3 where t=arctan(u/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try completing the square:

$$I=\int \frac {1}{{(x^2+2x+10)}^2}^~dx=\int \frac {1}{{((x+1)^2+9)}^2}^~dx$$

And let $$x+1=3\tan\theta \Rightarrow dx=3\sec^2\theta d\theta$$

So: $$I=\int \frac{3\sec^2\theta}{(9\tan^2\theta+9)^2}~d\theta=3\int \frac{\sec^2\theta}{81\sec^4\theta}^~d\theta=\frac{1}{27}\int \cos^2\theta d\theta=\frac{1}{27}(\frac{1}{2}\theta+\frac{1}{4}\sin(2\theta))$$ (See how to integrate $\cos^2\theta$)

$$=\frac{1}{27}(\frac{1}{2}\arctan(\tan\theta)+\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta \cos\theta)+C=\frac{1}{54}(\arctan(\tan\theta)+\frac{\tan\theta}{\sec^2\theta})+C=\frac{1}{54}(\arctan(\tan\theta)+\frac{\tan\theta}{\tan^2\theta+1})+C=\frac{1}{54}(\arctan(\frac{x+1}{3})+3\frac{x+1}{(x+1)^2+9})+C$$

Therefore:

$$\int_0^ {2} \frac {1}{{(x^2+2x+10)}^2}^~dx=\frac{1}{54}(\arctan(1)+\frac{1}{2}-\arctan(\frac{1}{3})-\frac{3}{10})=\frac{1}{54}(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\arctan(\frac{1}{3}))$$